# The local lipschitz condition implies differentiability?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I know differentiability implies the local lipschitz condition. however, I am not sure the converse.

Actually, I think it might be.

The definition of the local lipschitz condition is that for 
$$
f: A \subset \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n
$$
and $ \forall x_{0} \in A$, there are a constant $M > 0$ and a $\delta_{0} > 0$ such that $\lVert x- x_{0}\rVert < \delta_{0}$ implies 
$$
\lVert f(x) - f(x_{0})\rVert \leq M\lVert x-x_{0}\rVert
$$

And the definition of differentialbility is that $\lVert x-x_{0}\rVert < \delta $ implies
$$
\lVert f(x) - f(x_{0}) - Df(x_{0})(x-x_{0})\rVert < \epsilon \lVert x-x_{0}\rVert
$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x))=|x|$, which is Lipschitz but not differentiable.

However, [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) states that a (locally) Lipschitz function is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: what about in the case of locally? I know global Lipschitz condition does not imply the differentiability, but I am not sure the local Lipschitz condition implies the differentiability.

Comment: Any globally Lipschitz function is locally Lipschitz. (Also, but not quite so relevant here, given a locally Lipschitz function $f$ and a compact subset $K$ of the domain of $f$, there is a globally Lipschitz function which agrees with $f$ on $K$. So there is no difference between local properties of globally versos locally Lipschitz functions.)

Answer (score 6):

Think about $f(x)=|x|$. Is it (globally) Lipschitz continuous? What about differentiable?